# Java for loop is negative

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, negative-number

When you run below code

1. The `count` value becomes -1 and the program ends up with divide by zero exception.
2. When you uncomment the `sysout`, it runs fine. Not sure how `sysout` makes a diference.

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){

         int num = 1;
         int count;
         int sum;
         int fact;
         for(count=1,sum=0,fact=1;fact<=num;count=count+1){

            //System.out.println("num:"+num+" fact:"+fact+" count:"+count+" sum:"+sum);

             if(num%count==0){

                fact = num/count;
                sum  = sum+fact;
                System.out.println("num:"+num+" fact:"+fact+" count:"+count+" sum:"+sum);
             }

         }
    }
}
```

Output:

> num:1 fact:1 count:1 sum:1
>
> num:1 fact:-1 count:-1 sum:0
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
>           at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:14)

Comment: Are you certain the code you are showing generated this output?  If so, can you enable the first print statement and re-generate the output?

Comment: I am pretty sure what happened here is your looped through all int values.  1%1 would be true, but all other values of 1%n are false.  That is for positive values.  Once you overflow the int, I don't believe 1%0 is zero, so you don't attempt to print.  However, 1%-1 is zero I am guessing.  (I haven't looked at the formal definition of Modulus in awhile, but I think it is something like that.)  The bottom line is the "if" statement wasn't true on zero.  However, that doesn't explain why system.out.println() changes the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep incrementing count and it eventually overflows and wraps around to `0`.

```
In binary, Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647 = 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111                                              
                                            ^
                                            sign bit (positive)

When you add one more to the number it becomes

          Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648 = 1000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
                                            ^
                                            sign bit (negative)
```

So it wraps around and goes from Integer.MAX_VALUE to Integer.MIN_VALUE.

```
  for(int count=Integer.MAX_VALUE -10; count != Integer.MIN_VALUE + 10; count++){
         System.out.println("count = " + count);
  }
```

As you can see if you keep on adding `1` to `count`, it will eventually increment to `0` and you get the divide by `0` error.

You can read more about [Two's Complement Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

The count is defined as an integer when its value becomes bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE
its overflows and becomes negative.

As (1 % any number greater than 1) cannot be Zero, so the loop keeps continuing and the count value keeps growing and it overflows after Integer.MAX_VALUE loops.